# GetPoint() in Ray but with Padding and Angle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

This might be an odd question, but as fairly new to Unity I don't know how to go about my problem, but I find the Ray() class as one of the most useful classes for all kinds of work. Anyhow, to compute a given point of a Ray it's easy to call `.GetPoint(distance)`. - But is there a way to do a call like `.GetPoint(distance, padding, angle)`?

For instance, given the (3D) Ray from `a` to `b`

```
a--c----b
   |
   d
```

A call to `.GetPoint(3)` would return `c`, and a call to the wanted/new method `.GetPoint(3, 2, 0)` should return `d`. Further, calling `.GetPoint(3, 2, 90)` should return `d when it's behind (or above) c`.

*I guess I should have paid more attention in math class...*

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by the 3rd argument. Also, there's a whole circle of points that are at the end of a 90 degree segment of length 2 coming out of c, so it's ambiguous what point you would be interested in.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, I’ll try another way: For the Ray (a) to (b), the metod would calculate (c) using (distance), then pad away from the ray [in a right angle] with the distance of (padding), then rotate that point around the axis of the ray using (angle).

Comment: @FredrikJohansson Ruzihm's point is that there are an **infinite** number of directions perpendicular to a ray / line, so there's no way to *uniquely* determine the direction to "pad" in - unless you specify some other parameters (like a reference direction to perform the rotation relative to).

Comment: @FredrikJohansson Let me give you an example: A is at the origin (0,0,0) , and C is at (0,3,0).  Where would D be? Any point such that y=3, and z^2+x^2 = 4 would meet your criteria. You would need another parameter to indicate which of those points is "un rotated" so to speak. An example might be a direction vector that is perpendicular to a->b to indicate the "un rotated" direction

Comment: Yes, I think I see what you mean. I guess for my case the direction is not important :) - I’m trying to place & distribute some new objects around the axis of the ray, with a padding and at the certain distance. So say that the Ray is a line passing through the center of a clock face, then I’d like (padding) to be the distance to the numerals, and (angle) to determine the numeral to point at - which numeral I don’t mind, as long as 0-360 gives a full circle... I hope I understood you correctly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind Unity finding an arbitrary starting point, you can use [`Vector3.OrthoNormalize`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.OrthoNormalize.html) to get a starting point for you.

Then, you can use `Quaternion.AngleAxis` to rotate the point around the ray's direction (you have to offset the ray to/from the origin for the rotation operation).

```
Vector3 GetPaddedPoint(Ray ray, float distance, float padding, float angleInDegrees) 
{
    Vector3 rayDirection = ray.direction;
    Vector3 startingOrtho;
    Vector3.OrthoNormalize(ref rayDirection, ref startingOrtho);

    // Find some point padding from ray at distance from origin
    Vector3 axisPoint = ray.GetPoint(distance);
    Vector3 startingPoint = padding * startingOrtho+ axisPoint;

    // Find where startingPoint would be if the origin of the ray was at the origin
    Vector offsetPoint = startingPoint - ray.origin;

    // Rotate the offsetPoint around ray direction using Quaternion
    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angleInDegrees, rayDirection);
    Vector3 rotatedOffsetPoint = rotation * offsetPoint;

    // Add back in the ray's origin
    return rotatedOffsetPoint + ray.origin;

}
```

If you find that you prefer a particular kind of direction for a starting point, you can pass in a `startingOrtho`. Keep the `OrthoNormalize` call to ensure that it `startingOrtho` becomes orthogonal to the ray and normalized if it isn't already.

```
Vector3 GetPaddedPoint(Ray ray, float distance, float padding, float angleInDegrees, Vector3 startingOrtho) 
{
    Vector3 rayDirection = ray.direction;
    Vector3.OrthoNormalize(ref rayDirection, ref startingOrtho);

    // Find some point padding from ray at distance from origin
    Vector3 axisPoint = ray.GetPoint(distance);
    Vector3 startingPoint = padding * startingOrtho+ axisPoint;

    // Find where startingPoint would be if the origin of the ray was at the origin
    Vector offsetPoint = startingPoint - ray.origin;

    // Rotate the offsetPoint around ray direction using Quaternion
    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angleInDegrees, rayDirection);
    Vector3 rotatedOffsetPoint = rotation * offsetPoint;

    // Add back in the ray's origin
    return rotatedOffsetPoint + ray.origin;

}
```